# How to include a JSON query string in GET request in R?

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I'm new to R and coding. I'm trying to get some data by making a GET request in R and using the httr and josonlite packages.  I've made some successful API calls and parsed the data into a dataframe, but now need to include a JSON query string in my URL.  I've read similar questions and answers on Stack Overflow, but am still stumped as to what the best way to go about this is using R.  Can I simply encode the query string or do I need to set the query statements seperately (and if so what is the format needed).  Below is the URL i need to work with. 
Cheers!

```r
liz_URL <- "https://squidle.org/api/annotation_set?q={"order_by":[{"field":"created_at","direction":"desc"}],"filters":[{"name":"usergroups","op":"any","val":{"name":"id","op":"eq","val":49}}]}&results_per_page=100"
PQdata <- GET(liz_URL,add_headers("X-Auth-Token"="XXXXX"))
```

Comment: it most likely needs to be URL-encoded, use `htmltools::urlEncodePath` on a string to be able to `paste0` it to your base URL.

Comment: hmmm... unfortunately that returns an unexpected symbol error for anything inside double inverted commas in the query string.  `> query <- htmltools::urlEncodePath("?q={"order_by":[{"field":"created_at","direction":"desc"}],"filters":[{"name":"usergroups","op":"any","val":{"name":"id","op":"eq","val":49}}]}&results_per_page=100")
Error: unexpected symbol in "query <- htmltools::urlEncodePath("?q={"order_by"`

Comment: Well yes, you have unescaped quotes `"` within a `"` string. Either (a) enclose the whole thing in *single* quotes as `'?q={"order_by":...}'`, or (b) enclose in double quotes and put a backslash in front of every double-quote, as in `"q={\"order_by\":[{\"field\":\"created_at\"...}`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help with the unescaped quotes. Interestingly, this encodes the query but the response doesn't apply the query.  I did find that (manually) encoding only the double-quotes in the URL works.  For example, using `htmltools::urlEncodePath` creates a URL beginning with: `https://squidle.org/api/annotation_set?%3Fq%3D%7B%22order_by%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22created_at....` and that doesn't apply the query.  However a URL which retains all brackets but encodes double-quotes works:  `https://squidle.org/api/annotation_set?q={%22order_by%22:[{%22field%22:%22created_at...`  ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest, but the `?q=` must not be encoded, same with the `&results_per_page=`.